# Generate a react project/app in the browser for download

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to generate a react app in the browser based on certain variables that can be set in the site that would generate the react app. I looked around and haven't really found such a use case. The only solution I can think of is to generate it from a template without JSX so I can avoid the need of compiling it. Ideally I'd like to be able to download a "development" and a "build" version as well. Even directions where I should look are appreciated.

Comment: The cleanest way I can see is to store the variable values in a JSON file, then build the app on the server (the app loads the JSON and behaves accordingly), then zip up the build folder and start the download. However this question is much too broad for stackoverflow; what have you tried so far, where did you get stuck, and what have you attempted to get unstuck?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear about that part but the point is to generate this on the client side not on the server. I'll try to rephrase the question so this is clear.

Comment: Why do you want to generate it on the client? Is this going to be an offline project?

Comment: It's going to be an open source project where I'm not really sure about the traffic I would get and also don't really want the pain of putting it on a VPS so I'd like to host it as a static site via Github Pages.

Comment: I just want to point out the obvious: why not put the source of the React app on Github, and let people download and change *that*? Sure, they have to install node and compile it themselves, but is that bad enough to build an in-browser React app generator...?